# How can I select multiple count() rows in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, count

I'm working on a database to keep track of packages I need for a personal project. I am also treating this as an exercise to teach myself database design and SQL. The database I am using has a schema like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE packages
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
CREATE TABLE dependencies 
(
    dependentPackage INTEGER REFERENCES pages(ID),
    requiredPackage INTEGER REFERENCES pages(ID)
);
```

where the package referenced by dependencies.dependentPackage depends on the package referenced by dependencies.requiredPackage
I want a query with a column NumPackagesRequired, which returns a table that looks something like this:

```
packageName | NumDependencies
package1 | 6
package5 | 8
package9 | 1
```

I cannot achieve this by trying:

```
SELECT p.name AS packageName, count (d.requiredPackage) AS numDependencies
FROM packages p
JOIN dependencies d ON d.dependentPackage=p.ID;
```

because it returns only one row, containing the first package's name and the count of all the requirements.
I tried nesting a SELECT statement as a parameter to the count() function, but I still only got a single row of results. I have searched the sqlite documentation with no degree of luck.

How can I get a table like the one expected above?

Comment: I think you are looking for `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using GROUP BY, aggregate functions are computed over each group:

```
SELECT p.name AS packageName,
       count (d.requiredPackage) AS numDependencies
FROM packages p
JOIN dependencies d ON d.dependentPackage=p.ID
GROUP BY p.name;
```

Alternatively, move the couting into a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT name AS packageName,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM dependencies
        WHERE dependentPackage = packages.ID
       ) AS numDependencies
FROM packages;
```